# AWS network performance: t2 vs m5

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I noticed network issues on t2 instance types which disappeared while using m5. I understand that m5 types have more bandwidth, however for my use I would have expected t2 to be enough (my local desktop works fine for this) so there is something else going on.

I need to listen to some websockets - about 100-300 Kb/s in total, which doesn't seem much. However, on t2 instances types I get disconnected every 10-20mins.

Is there something fundamentally different about t2 instance types that could explain poor connectivity to websockets? It's far worse than my home connection, which isn't particularly performant. Using m5 instances for this use case seems like an overkill and is much more costly.

Comment: What size of t2 instance? Are you sure you're not running out of cpu or ebs credits?

Answer (score 0):

Network cards on some instances, including t2, result in CPU usage. On a system with CPU credits like t2, that will drain the CPU credits resulting in poor performance. I’d suggest going with t2 unlimited or an m class instance as a way to mitigate.

Comment: Thank you. After more reading, I think you are right. I was assuming t2 would be fine for simple networking use cases by looking at the bandwidth... however CPU needs to be considered too.